# Getting length of "slices" of NumPy array (or list) without actually slicing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose that I have a NumPy array `arr` like

```
array([5, 3, 0, 5, 7, 6, 5, 9, 0, 6])
```

and a few included indices in another array, `inds`,

```
array([3, 6])
```

**I want to generate** an array with the lengths of the subarrays of `arr` *were* I to split my array with `inds`. So in this case, my result would be `[3, 3, 4]`.

---

I know that I could use `np.split` to do

```
>>> np.split(arr, inds)
[array([5, 3, 0]), array([5, 7, 6]), array([5, 9, 0, 6])]
```

and map `size()` to get the correct result of `[3, 3, 4]` from there, but it seems like an unnecessary cost to *actually* split the array given that I'm just using the size of the subarrays - this information is obviously available without splitting (from the indices), but how can I effectively use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach with concatenation of the endpoints (0 and the length of array) on either sides of the indices array and then use diferentiation to get the interval lengths -

```
np.diff(np.concatenate(([0], inds, [arr.size])))
```

Shorter alternative -

```
np.diff(np.r_[0, inds, arr.size])
```

For performance we could use difference between `one-off shifted slices` to replace the differentiation with `np.diff` -

```
inds_ext = np.concatenate(([0], inds, [arr.size]))
out = inds_ext[1:] - inds_ext[:-1]
```

Comment: Ahh this makes sense, just place the endpoints and then it is easy. Thanks  Divakar!