# Determine length of numpy array or sequence after slicing without actually slicing

Tags: python, slice

I have a `slice` object and I'd like to determine the length of the array (or sequence) that would result from using it to slice an array of known shape, **without** actually constructing the array.

So the reference implementation is:

```py
def length_after_slice(input_len: int, s: slice):
    return np.empty(input_len)[s].size
```

but this implementation constructs the array and thus uses unnecessary memory.

[Getting length of "slices" of NumPy array (or list) without actually slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370491/getting-length-of-slices-of-numpy-array-or-list-without-actually-slicing) is closely related but differs in it's input format - specifically, slice objects have the `step` attribute and can have negative or `None` start/stop indices which the provided answer there cannot immediately handle.

Naturally, a pythonic one/two-liner "trick" (optionaly using numpy) is preferred over nested conditionals that equates each index to `None` and checks it's sign.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense to me. In order to slice an array, you must also know the start and end indices of the slice. Why would you need to actually make the slice in order to know the length if you already know those two parameters? It's just `end - start`

Comment: @roganjosh: That doesn't handle negative steps, or steps at all, or negative slice endpoints, or slice endpoints beyond the array bounds.

Comment: This operation *can* of course be implemented without actually slicing an array, but it's more complicated than that.

Comment: @roganjosh, also slice endpoints can be `None`

Comment: Fair enough. I certainly didn't read this kind of complexity from the question as-given, but I totally concede

Comment: I would posit that this has nothing to do with numpy at all. Slices work the same way for any other sequence.

Comment: Inspired by the related (linked) question and answer - I thought numpy might be part of a good **solution**, which satisfies my use case, and therefore the numpy flavoring. I agree this applies to any sequence though as mentioned in the title and question body.

Comment: You can use this: `len(range(*aSlice.indices(aSize)))`.  It is much shorter than the solutions in the linked answer.

Comment: @AlainT. Which answer are you referring to?